# Java thermal printer: Bottom margin before auto cut

Tags: java, printing

I have a java program, which send jobs to a thermal printer. It prints ok, but it auto cut the paper just after the last image o text without a margin.

How can I set a bottom margin? I have tried printing empty strings or space characters but it it doesn't print it cuts before.

I'm using java.awt.print.

Thanks

```
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);


    PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
    double width = 3 * 72;
    double height = 200000;// * 72;
    double margin = 0;// * 72;
    paper.setSize(width, height);
    paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, width - (margin * 2), height - (margin * 2));

    pf.setPaper(paper);


    job.setPrintable(this,  pf);

    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try to set a vertical margin? You are using one single margin for vertical and horizontal of 0 right now.

Comment: You should specify what library you use since the answer depends on it.

Comment: If giving extra margin does not work, just add a small white image at the end with the height you want as margin

Comment: Fildor, how can I do it?

Nicolas, I have just added:  java.awt.print.

Salem, It doesn't run, if nothing is printed it cuts automatically as if I print a empty string or "   "